# How can I change many data indices using loop statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

```
bz1 = [90100, 90200, 90300, 90400, 90500, 90600, 90700, 90800, 90900, 91000,
       91100, 91200, 91300, 91400, 91500, 91600, 91700, 91800, 91900, 92000,
       92100, 92200, 92300]
bz2 = [1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090, 1100,
       1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1160, 1170, 1180, 1190, 1200,
       1210, 1220, 1230]
#1. bz1[0], bz2[0]

#2. df6.replace(bz1[0],bz2[0])

for i in range(22):
    h = df6.replace(bz1[i],bz2[i])
h
```

*I'm interested in programming, so I'm a self-taught Python beginner.
I've been practicing a lot myself using pandas lately :)*

**I want to change the names in bz1 to the names in bz2.

It was possible with methods #1 and #2, but I tried to change all index names more simply with a 'for' loop, but it doesn't work at all. Also, there is no error message.

I wonder what the problem is and how to easily change numerous data indexes into a loop statement.**

Comment: Using loops like that with pandas is rarely the right choice. Every time you change (mutate) a frame or series, you create a new object. Pandas is ***not*** designed to be used like that. It's slow and inefficient. Pandas is intended to operate on whole frames or series at once.

Answer (score 1):

If need replace values in all columns create dictionary by `dict` and `zip`:

```
df6.replace(dict(zip(bz1,bz2)))
```

If need replace indices use [`DataFrame.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df6.rename(dict(zip(bz1,bz2)))
```

If need replace columns names:

```
df6.rename(columns=dict(zip(bz1,bz2)))
```

Another idea is create dictionary by arithmetic:

```
d = {x: (x - 80000)//10 for x in bz1}
print (d)

{90100: 1010, 90200: 1020, 90300: 1030, 90400: 1040, 90500: 1050,
 90600: 1060, 90700: 1070, 90800: 1080, 90900: 1090, 91000: 1100,
 91100: 1110, 91200: 1120, 91300: 1130, 91400: 1140, 91500: 1150, 
 91600: 1160, 91700: 1170, 91800: 1180, 91900: 1190, 92000: 1200,
 92100: 1210, 92200: 1220, 92300: 1230}
```

Sample data:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)}, index=[90400,91700,92300])
print (df6)
       a
90400  0
91700  1
92300  2

df = df6.rename(dict(zip(bz1,bz2)))
print (df)
      a
1040  0
1170  1
1230  2


df = df6.rename({x: (x - 80000)//10 for x in bz1})
print (df)
      a
1040  0
1170  1
1230  2
```